# Postgresql tree data structure

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have installed Postgresql 9.2 and would like to use LTREE data type.
When I try to create table as in the documentation.

```
CREATE TABLE test (path ltree);
```

I have error: `type ltree does not exist`
I use pgAdmin III for this query. What am I doing wrong? Should I install this module separately. If yes, how?
P.S. OS Windows.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need to install the ltree extension by running:

```
CREATE EXTENSION ltree;
```

as a superuser.

See the manual for details: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createextension.html

You might also want to read up on [recursive queries](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/queries-with.html) which let query this kind of data structure in a "regular table" using a `parent_id`